# Adding EWS Java API

Tags: android, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am trying to add EWS Java API 1.2 to my android app. I followed the same procedure given in [this link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28952/android-mail-client-using-exchange-web-services)

I generated jar file and added thet to my android library. But when i try to access any of the class from this jar file i am getting

```
 noclassdefinition found exception
```

I also tried this way of building java library for android by removing JRE from libraries and adding the android jars . But here also same error. Please help . I am really stuck.
What is the right way to do it. I did lot of searches but didnt get any right help.

http://geekswithblogs.net/cyberycon/archive/2011/05/17/using-external-libraries-with-android.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Exchange Online on Office 365, then you should consider the client SDK for the OData API for Android:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Android